# x86_64 Linux syscall arguments

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, system-calls, abi

I'm learning x86_64 assembly on Linux and I've run into some conflicting information that I was hoping could get cleared up. On one hand, I've read that for syscall arguments, you would use registers in the order of rdi, rsi, rdx, and so on. But on the other hand I've read that you use the registers rbx, rcx, rdx, and so on. One person told me that the reasoning for this is because of ABI, but I'm not totally understanding what that exactly means.

Why are there two formats for this and which would be the proper one to use?

Answer (score 13):

According to [this Wikibooks page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Interfacing_with_Linux), it depends on which instruction you are using to perform the syscall.

- If you are using `int $0x80` (the 32-bit ABI with call numbers from `asm/unistd_32.h`), then you should use `eax` for the syscall number, and `ebx`, `ecx`, `edx`, `esi`, `edi`, and `ebp` for the parameters (in that order).
- If you are using the `syscall` instruction (the 64-bit ABI with native call numbers from `asm/unistd.h`), you should use `rax` for the syscall number and `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, `r10`, `r8`, and `r9` for the parameters.

[What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-i386-and-x86-6)

In 64-bit mode `syscall` is preferred because it's faster, available on all x86-64 Linux kernels, and supports 64-bit pointers and integers.  The `int 0x80` ABI truly takes input in `ecx`, not `rcx`, for example, making it unusable for `write` or `read` of a buffer on the stack in 64-bit code.
[What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code).

Comment: Well, considering I'm using x86_64, I would use `syscall`. I just have seen examples where `rbx` `rcx` and `rdx` are used as arguments (in that order) and was confused as to why.

Comment: @Chiggins Any chance you could point us to the examples where `rbx`, `rcx` and `rdx` are used for syscalls using x86_64? I am just curious.

Comment: @Chiggins Well, either the code sample doesn't work, or Wikibooks is wrong.  You can write a test case pretty easily.  Put one set of arguments in `rdi`, `rsi`, etc., and a different set in `rbx` and so on.  Invoke the syscall and see which set of arguments were used.

Comment: @augurar The code sample works, I've compiled and tested it myself.

Comment: @Chiggins The code sample is inconsistent in which registers it uses for arguments.  If it works, it's only by coincidence.

Comment: @Chiggins note that the first two syscalls in your link, using the wrong set of registers, simply zero them out. But zero is the value (almost) all the registers have on program entry point, so these `xor`s are actually no-ops. This is why the program may work for you, although it sometimes passes parameters wrongly.